# Guessing game in C with while loops and if statements debugging

Tags: c, debugging, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

So I'm creating a program that's a guessing game. It's supposed to ask player 1 to enter a number between 0 and 99, if they enter anything outside of that the code should ask them to retry this.

Then it will ask for a number of guesses/attempts Player 2 has to enter what they think the number is. If it's too high the program will say so, if it's too low the program will say so. If it's just right- Player 2 wins and if they run out of guesses the program is to say that too.

My problem is with the second half of this code. Where I'm trying to fit in the number of guesses with the remaining guesses. The loop isn't working; here's the code:

```
  int secretnumber;
  int guesses;
  int secretnumberguess;
  int remainingguesses;

  while (1)  {
    printf("Player 1: Type a number between 0 and 99 and press return:\n");
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumber);

    if (secretnumber > 99 || secretnumber < 0) {
      printf("Secret number cannot be greater than 99 or below 0.\n");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  printf( "Type the number of guesses that player 2 gets and press return: \n");
  scanf("%d",&guesses);

  remainingguesses = guesses - 1;

  while (remainingguesses != 0)  {
    printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",&remainingguesses);
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumberguess);

    if (secretnumberguess > secretnumber) {
      printf("Your guess was greater than the secret number.\n");

      else if (secretnumberguess < secretnumber)
        printf("Your guess was less than the secret number.\n");

        else (secretnumberguess == secretnumber)
               printf("Your guess was equal to the secret number. You win!\n");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  if (remainingguesses == 0)
    printf("Sorry you are out of guesses. You lose.\n");
```

I'm entirely new to this and trying to debug and fix my code. But loops are truly a nightmare for me especially when you throw if statements into the mix. I realize I'm very incompetent and I apologize but could someone help me as I'm totally confused on the second half of my code.

Comment: You decrement (decrease) the number of remaining guesses outside the while loop. Therefore, the number of remaining guesses never reaches zero and your loop never terminates.  Move the decrement to just after you get the next guess from the user instead. (This would be an excellent time to learn to use a debugger to step through the code; it would have identified the problem for you in one or two passes through the loop. A debugger is one of the most powerful tools you'll ever use when solving problems with your code; learn to use one early.)

Comment: `&remainingguesses` is the location in memory where the variable `remainingguesses` is stored. You probably don't want to print that. Try reading the warning messages from your compiler. And learn how to use a debugger too (like GDB or LLDB, for example).

Comment: For future reference, phrases like *the loop isn't working* are not problem statements unless you explain specifically what *not working* means. In this case, the problem is that the loop is never terminating, so you should say that instead of *not working*. If you want help, *be specific* and clearly state the problem.

Comment: If you're ever confused about what code does, sit down with a pencil and paper and pretend you're the computer. Work through every single line, skipping _nothing_, with some input. It's slow, but the more you do it, the better you get at it, and the more easily you can do it in your head. Plus, the patience it builds is invaluable later on, when you have to dig through hundreds or thousands of lines of code to find a single missing function call that's causing kilobytes of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this code:

```
while (remainingguesses != 0)  {
    printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",&remainingguesses);
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumberguess);
```

is wrong. When using the `printf` statement and you are trying to input the variable in the statement, you don't need to put `&` in it.

So you need to change you code to:

```
while (remainingguesses != 0)  {
    printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",remainingguesses);
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumberguess);
```

You need to remove `&` in the `printf` statement. We only use `&` like to store something into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Write code step by step, respecting proper syntax and understanding what you want to accomplish next. Don't rush. It just takes time to learn and programming is no different.

```
remainingguesses = guesses - 1;
```

The variable *remainingguesses* controls your loop, but you only assign a value to it once and never change it afterwards. The loop will then never end. After correcting this, ask yourself: How many guesses will I be able to do if I enter 3 guesses?

```
printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",&remainingguesses);
```

Here you are printing the memory address that holds the value *remainingguesses*, not its actual value. This is the concept behind pointers, which I advise you to research in order to get a proper understanding of the mechanics involved here.

```
if (secretnumberguess > secretnumber) {
  printf("Your guess was greater than the secret number.\n");

  else if (secretnumberguess < secretnumber)
    printf("Your guess was less than the secret number.\n");

    else (secretnumberguess == secretnumber)
           printf("Your guess was equal to the secret number. You win!\n");
  continue;
}
break;
```

Careful with those braces! The entire block will be entered only if the guess is bigger than the secretnumber. In any other case, execution will just jump to the *break* and then exit the *while* loop. I believe this mixup caused you to confuse the usage of **continue** and **break**, too.

**Else** acts as a contingency for your conditional statements. It doesn't need a boolean value nor a comparison like the one you're using. In other words, if the guessed number is neither bigger nor smaller than the secret one, it's guaranteed to be equal to it.

This has been mentioned already but I can't stress it enough: Pay attention to the compiler. Research every error and warning it provides you. You will make sure progress this way.